# How to achieve 3D eges effect in a way like in this tutorial? Missing button

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have found two tutorials. Both in languages I don't undrestand.
In both they are using the same easy and fantastic technique and a button I can't find in my Adobe Photosop. 
Button: arrow with '+'.
Because of language I don't know how does it call, and where to find it.

I'm using a new trial version, and I haven't got this button there.
Both tutorial begin from the right place.
[first tutorial](https://youtu.be/XOL7tLYbuVM?t=461) and 
[second tutorial](https://youtu.be/E-km1doyxTg?t=145)

Comment: Have you searched for photoshop commands or photoshop tools elsewhere? That arrow on the right side of the marquee tool is the 'move' tool.

Comment: Arrow with a + is just the move tool?

Answer (score 0):

The first video is in Italian, and he does this:

1. Select the move tool (V).
2. click on the level you want in 3d.
3. Now, click alt, and **while keeping it clicked** -*without touching the mouse*- click on the UP arrow in your keyboard many times. this will duplicate the layer in the same direction, many times.
4. select all the layers except the top one and merge them (ctrl+e)
5. Darken the stack of layers to create the shadowed effect *(you can do this in many different ways, one of them is through hue/saturation (ctrl+u) and then lowering the lightness)*.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the layer you want to give 3d Effect to
2. Press both <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> together and then press the <kbd>down</kbd> key, which will duplicate the layers in the direction of the arrow
3. Once you are done duplicating merge all the layers below the top layer
4. After that select the merged layer then go to layer properties set color overlay to black and decrease the opacity to your need approx 20-30%
5. Now you have made the mock up merge both the layers!

And you are done!